# why are the results of variable and condition are different?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I was wondering to figure out this problem.

In the below query am trying to select @transcript as the combination of 2 column values. but when i am using this variable in select statement am getting only 3 results (actual output should be 8 results). where as when i use the condition directly in select statement am getting actual output.

can anybody please help me in figuring out this issue.

```
declare @transcript varchar(10)
select @transcript = [CAREER_CD]+[CAREER_SUFX_CD] from dbo.SR0DAT
select DISTINCT @transcript transcriptCareerCode, 
case @transcript
     when 'U1' then 'BACCALAUREATE'
     when 'U2' then 'SECOND BACCALAUREATE'
     when 'G1' then 'GRADUATE'
     when 'L1' then 'LAW'
     when 'D1' then 'DENTISTRY'
     when 'M1' then 'MEDICINE'
     when 'IU' then 'transcriptCareerName'
     when 'IG' then 'IEO Graduate'
     end as transcriptCareerName
from dbo.SR0DAT
WHERE @transcript <>'G2'
union
select 'IU','IEO Undergraduate'
union
select 'IG','IEO Graduate'
```

output:

```
transcriptCareerCode    transcriptCareerName
G1  GRADUATE
IG  IEO Graduate
IU  IEO Undergraduate
```

2nd code:

```
select DISTINCT [CAREER_CD]+[CAREER_SUFX_CD] transcriptCareerCode, 
case [CAREER_CD]+[CAREER_SUFX_CD]
     when 'U1' then 'BACCALAUREATE'
     when 'U2' then 'SECOND BACCALAUREATE'
     when 'G1' then 'GRADUATE'
     when 'L1' then 'LAW'
     when 'D1' then 'DENTISTRY'
     when 'M1' then 'MEDICINE'
     when 'IU' then 'transcriptCareerName'
     when 'IG' then 'IEO Graduate'
     end as transcriptCareerName
from dbo.SR0DAT
WHERE [CAREER_CD]+[CAREER_SUFX_CD] !='G2'
union
select 'IU','IEO Undergraduate'
union
select 'IG','IEO Graduate'
```

output:

```
transcriptCareerCode    transcriptCareerName
D1  DENTISTRY
G1  GRADUATE
IG  IEO Graduate
IU  IEO Undergraduate
L1  LAW
M1  MEDICINE
U1  BACCALAUREATE
U2  SECOND BACCALAUREATE
```

Comment: Please tag dbms used. (This doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all...)

Comment: When you don't intend to remove duplicates, do UNION ALL instead of just UNION [DISTINCT].

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply jarlh,  I don't want to keep the duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both queries are indeed run against your table none of its columns are being used at all in the first one: for each row you're simply returning a fixed/constant expression. The `distinct` option is helping to mask what's going on and if you remove the that you'll see all of the multiple copies that are being collapsed into one row. If you also say `select @transcript, * ...` you'll see where the rest of the data is as well.

Are you just trying to accomplish an alias for the `transcript` expression so you don't have to repeat it?

```
with T as (
    select CAREER_CD + CAREER_SUFX_CD as transcript
    from dbo.SR0DAT
)
select DISTINCT
    transcript transcriptCareerCode, 
    case transcript
        when 'U1' then 'BACCALAUREATE'
        when 'U2' then 'SECOND BACCALAUREATE'
        when 'G1' then 'GRADUATE'
        when 'L1' then 'LAW'
        when 'D1' then 'DENTISTRY'
        when 'M1' then 'MEDICINE'
        when 'IU' then 'transcriptCareerName'
        when 'IG' then 'IEO Graduate'
    end as transcriptCareerName
from T
where transcript <> 'G2'
union
select 'IU', 'IEO Undergraduate'
union
select 'IG', 'IEO Graduate'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Its giving actual result with the above code.

Comment: Adding one for the sake that your communication skills rock. You understood what sam was trying to do.

Comment: @Paurian, the timing of your comment is absolutely incredible and I appreciate it greatly. Of course you also identified the problem very quickly and gave an accurate answer in that sense. I've been a little down on SO lately but I am grateful to know that not all is lost!

Answer (score 1):

In your first query you are creating a singular value through the variable @transcript. As a result, your call to:

```
select @transcript = [CAREER_CD]+[CAREER_SUFX_CD] from dbo.SR0DAT
```

Only guarantees that the last record in the SELECT statement gets assigned to the @transcript variable.

As a result, only one row from that query will return (you've union'ed the other two rows in your first example).

The second example is using actual database set logic to pull in values across the set - not just the last value in the set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.   Is there any way by modifying the 1st statement i could achieve the output ??

Comment: Just a side note that removing the `distinct` will help make this more clear (for your understand not the final results.)

Comment: Your short answer is to get rid of your variable. The code you have in example 1 is a common snag for developers, who are used to writing code, venturing into dataset logic/theory. When you are working in databases, you are pulling sets of data. Adding a variable to the mix forces a singular result from the set. Perhaps you can post what you're wanting to achieve. I understood your question as an inquiry to why your code works the way it does.

Comment: BTW - in your first example, removing your "DISTINCT" (which is usually misused to hide Cartesian  products) in your first query would cause a ton of rows that look like the first row in your result. That would reveal something strange since I'm sure not all the rows in your table contain "G1". You should also use an auxiliary table that maps the values instead of using a case statement. These are other common mistakes developers make when entering the DB world.

Comment: What would you like to achieve? Why are you wanting to use a variable?